# Questions on 'Existence of least upper bound'

Tags: analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Corollary and Theorem come from the Analysis I textbook of Tao. My question is how we get $K/n \geq M$ and $L/n \lt x_0$ based on Archimedean property. My solution is this: If $M$ is a non-positive real number,then we can find a positive integer $K$; If $M$ is positive,then $K$ must be positive, thus we can find $K$ such that $Kn＞M$ or $KM＞n$ according to Archimedean property,but none gets $K/n \geq M$. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $M=x$ and $1/n=\epsilon$. That even gives you the slightly stronger, but for the proof unnecessary, $K/n>M$. The choice of the name $M$ for two different things is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you, and what about $L/n \lt x_0$? By Archimedean property, exists a $n≥1$ such that $nx_0>L$?

Comment: Or, According to Archimedean property,$M\epsilon\gt x$,then we have $\frac x\epsilon \lt M$. Take $L=x, \epsilon=1/n,M=x_0$ ,Thus we get $L/n \lt x_0$. Are those two solutions right?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that part of your question. Neither of your attempts seem right. In the first one, the problem is that we have already chosen a fixed $n$, so we cannot use that as a variable anymore. Similarly, in your second attempt, the Archimedean property guarantees the existence of such an $M$, but it need not be $x_{0}$. Frankly, I don't see why or how we would use the Archimedean property here. Take any integer $y$ smaller than $x_{0}$ and put $L=ny$.

Comment: Or perhaps you have not seen yet that an integer smaller than $x_{0}$ always exists?

Comment: you're right.  there's the proposition 5.4.12 in the book: Let x be a positive
real number. Then there exists a positive rational number q such that
$q ≤ x$.